# How to disable "ioncube" from cpanel?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, cpanel, ioncube

I'm facing an issue to disable the ioncude encryption from my Laravel PHP code from Cpanel.
I unchecked ioncube from WHM simply accessing the Home > Server Configuration > Tweek settings and then in the PHP section as shown below.

[image]

I don't know what's wrong with it because after unchecking ioncube my code is still encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cPanel "ioncube" is just a PHP Extension (ioncube loader) that helps you to make encrypted(with ioncube Encrypted) code executable.

For decode ioncube you can visit : https://easytoyou.eu/decoder/demophp54